# Joint probability of dependent sums of uniform random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Suppose $A_i$ are independent uniformly distributed random variables on possibly different intervals: $A_i \sim U(0,b_i)$. I am interested in determining the probability that:
\begin{equation}
\left( \sum_{i=n}^{N}A_i \leq C_1 \quad \cap \quad \sum_{j=m}^{M}A_j \leq C_2 \right)
\end{equation}
where $m>n$ and $M>N$, but $m\leq N$. That is, the intervals $[n,N]$ and $[m,M]$ overlap. This means that some of the random variables appear in both sums, so the LHS and RHS are not independent.

I am struggling to understand how to relate the two sums to be able to determine their joint probability. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Theoretically, you conditional on the overlapped random variables, then you will make the two events become independent. However it requires a high-dimensional integral in general, and in fact the probability of each event will be even more complicated then the Irwin-Hall distribution (as $b_i$ are different in general). So the only hope is that when the number of random variable is very small (which you compute exactly / numerically), or otherwise when it is very large, and $b_i$ are nice enough to satisfy the Lyapunov condition to apply a multivariate CLT.

Comment: @BGM thanks for your reply! However, I’m not sure exactly what you mean with conditional on the overlapped random variables? Do you mean trying to take the overlapping variables out of the sums and introducing another event $\sum_{k} A_{k} \leq C_3$ where $k$ are the overlapping variables? Also, I’m happy to apply the CLT here and assume the sums of the uniform RVs follow a Normal distribution since the number of $A_i$s is relatively large in my case. Does this simplify the matter?